# Facebook FQL like_count is 0 only for a particular page

Tags: facebook-fql

Hi I am trying to get the number of likes without using the access token.

I came across this link and tried with different accounts.

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://www.facebook.com/8daysmagazine%27&format=json

Out of all, only one account, the number of likes returned is wrong, which is 0 when it should be more than that.

http://www.facebook.com/8daysmagazine

I am not sure where went wrong and would like to seek your help. I understand that Facebook fql has been deprecated, but I would like to use this instead of Graph API as I dont wish to create an access token everytime.

Thank you.

Comment: fql will be gone forever soon (august 2016), so why use it? it´s no big deal to use an access token, just use an "app access token": http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/ - also, the graph api is a lot easier than fql.

Comment: alright thank you @luschn, managed to do it in the graph api way :)